# Populate the dropdownlist from a specfic year to current year

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating a dropdownlist of year.
How can I automatically populate the dropdownlist?

For example, I will be adding a dropdown value 1980, can I use jQuery to populate it to the current year, so I will not need to type all the year?

Comment: Please when asking questions try always to show some code, your best try, so people can give you more guidance, not only answer with snippets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simple using a for loop and adding to string like:

```js
var nowY = new Date().getFullYear(),
    options = "";

for(var Y=nowY; Y>=1980; Y--) {
  options += "<option>"+ Y +"</option>";
}

$("#years").append( options );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="years"></select>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getFullYear
http://api.jquery.com/append/

Answer (score 5):

You can use a `for` loop between `1980` and the current year, which you can retrieve through the `getFullYear()` property of a Date object. Try this:

```
var html = '';
for (var i = 1980; i <= new Date().getFullYear(); i++) {
    html += '<option value="' + i + '">' + i + '</option>';
}
$('#mySelect').html(html);
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/8np1qjfw/)

If you'd prefer to start with the current year and work down, you can use a negative iteration, like this:

```
for (var i = new Date().getFullYear(); i >= 1980; i--) {
    html += '<option value="' + i + '">' + i + '</option>';
}
```

Comment: No problem, glad to help.

Comment: Rory, It's actually nicer to start with current year I think and go down to 1980. Add that one to question as well ;) only with `i--` ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a for loop (http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp)

```
function fillDates(startDate){
    yr = new Date().getFullYear();
    options = "";
    for(var i=startDate, i<=yr, i++){
        options += ("<option value = "+i+">"+i+"</option");
    }
    $("select").append(options);
}


fillDates(1908);
```

Comment: And when when we go into `2017`... then ? .

Comment: don't ever use `.append()` within a loop. It's not efficient to query the DOM for a selector and alter the view triggering layout change and repaints etc etc... Use string concatenation - Append once.

Comment: @Rayon Dabr then he'll search the web and find out about the date function, wasn't included in the question

Comment: @Roko C. Buljan I agree

Answer (score 0):

chong there are lots of answers, i am little bit let to update my answer to jsFiddle.

fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/eua98tqa/8/

HTML:

```
<html>

  <head>
  </head>

 <body>

 <select>
 </select>

 </body>

</html>
```

jQuery:

```
var fromYear = 1980;
var currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();

for (var i = fromYear; i <= currentYear; i++) {
 $("select").append('<option value="' + i + '">' + i + '</option>');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have more than one year dorpdowns, for which I wanted to compute year list from one specific year till current year. Commenting my final solution, may be somebody can find this useful:

```
function populateYearList(minYear, currentYear, selectElement){
    var max = currentYear, min = minYear;
    for (var i = min; i<=max; i++) {
        var opt = document.createElement('option');
        opt.value = i;
        opt.innerHTML = i;
        selectElement.append(opt);
    }
       //selecting current year by default and adding "selected" attribute to it
    $(selectElement).val(max)
        .find("option[value=" + max +"]")
        .attr("selected","selected");
}
```

calling on page load

```
var selectElement = $('.select-class');
populateYearList('2015', currentYear, selectElement);
```

Answer (score -1):

please refer code below

```
<input type="text" id="inputyear">
<select id="selectyear">

</select>
<input type="button" value="Generate" onclick="FillYears()">

<script type="text/javascript">
function FillYears(){
for(var i=parseInt($("#inputyear").val());i<=(new Date().getFullYear());i++)
{
    $("#selectyear").append($("<option>"+i+"</option>"));
}
}
</script>
```

Comment: Since that's almost an exact copy of Velimir's answer >> **See my comments on Velimir's answer.**

Comment: Try always to keep JS away from HTML, I know yours is an example, but you'd go better with `addEventListener` instead of inlining JS calls.

Comment: it's not exact copy @RokoC.Buljan. i have created my own example.